# How does Wikipedia calculate days elapsed?

Tags: date, web, timezone, wikipedia

I've seen many cases on Wikipedia in which the number of days elapsed is displayed. As an example [look here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21st_century) On the second line there is the text:

> The century began on January 1, 2001 and will end on December 31, 2100. As of now, 11 years and 343 days of the 21st century have passed.

How does Wikipedia calculate elapsed days? How does it work with different timezone?
This even works with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: The actual MediaWiki template code that does this calculation can be found in [Template:Age in years and days textual version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Age_in_years_and_days_textual_version) and its subtemplates on Wikipedia. Be warned, though: it's really ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works with Javascript disabled that means it's being calculated server-side. Most likely it's being calculated by PHP within MediaWiki.

Here's info on what technology Wikipedia is using: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:FAQ/Technical

This is a PHP script to calculate the number of days elapsed since a date:

```
<?php

     $now = time(); // or your date as well
     $your_date = strtotime("2010-01-01");
     $datediff = $now - $your_date;
     echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));

?>
```

To insert that information on a Wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Age_in_days

Comment: If you like to add days elapsed into another page on wikipedia, how would you do that? As per my knowledge cannot include PHP while editing. Then how is this done? What about different timezones?

Comment: @NikhilDamle This page includes information on how to do that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Date_mathematics_templates